# weka StringToWordVector filter reversion (java)

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, text-mining

I can't deal with clustering with **weka** library. I have string attributes, so I use StringToWordVector filter, but how can I after clustering move back from WordVector to string representation to show 'human readable' results?
I want to revert this operation:

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
filter.setInputFormat(instancesToFilter);
Instances dataFiltered = Filter.useFilter(instancesToFilter, filter);
```

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringToWordVector` filter cannot be reversed. However, you have at least two possibilities:

- If you just want to see or show the original strings that are in each cluster, you can add an `ID` attribute, ensure it is not used during clustering (to avoid unexpected behavior), then recover the text from the original strings (`ARFF` file).
- If you want to show some meaningful summary of the contents of each cluster, you can just output the most frequent/heavy words in each cluster. This is a rather common approach when clustering texts.

Answer (score 1):

The filter is **lossy**.

As such, there cannot exist an (exact) reverse transformation. You can maybe approximate it somehow, though.

Consider looking at the source code of the filter.